# Mysql Select events from last year but not this year

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join, self-join

I need some direction on a query.

I have an orders table. It has the following columns (among others)

```
OrderID | OrderDate | CustomerID
```

I want to find customers who ordered in 2012, but have not ordered in 2013.

(and actually I will eventually want more precision (customers who ordered in March of 2012, but not 2013))

I know I could do two queries -

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN 2012-01-01 AND 2012-12-31"
"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN 2013-01-01 AND 2013-12-31"
```

and then analyze the results, but it seems like it ought to be possible with pure mysql.

Perhaps a self join? Or a nested SELECT? I'm not very familiar with these and am having a hard time finding a relevant example. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eggyal's answer will work, but it could be very slow since it can't make use of indexes. Assuming you have an index on `OrderDate`, the following self-JOIN may be better:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o1.CustomerID
FROM Orders o1
LEFT JOIN Orders o2
ON o1.CustomerID = o2.CustomerID
AND o2.OrderDate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31 23:59:59'
WHERE o1.Orderdate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31 23:59:59'
AND o2.CustomerID IS NULL
```

Comment: Well I really liked the simplicity of eggyal's answer, but I had to choose this one because it was 3 times faster and, in the end, will be more scalable to different uses. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No joins required; just filter the orders when grouped on customer:

```sql
SELECT   CustomerID
FROM     Orders
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING   SUM(OrderDate BETWEEN 2012-03-01 AND 2012-03-31)
 AND NOT SUM(OrderDate BETWEEN 2013-01-01 AND 2013-12-31)
```

Comment: This could be a very slow query if the table is large, as it can't be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

My query is more readable. Just subtraction customers of 2013 from customers of 2012.

```
SELECT `CustomerID` 
FROM `d` 
WHERE 
   `OrderDate` BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31 23:59:59' 
   AND `CustomerID` NOT IN
       (SELECT `CustomerID` 
        FROM `d` 
        WHERE 
            `OrderDate` BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31 23:59:59' 
        GROUP BY `CustomerID`)
   GROUP BY `CustomerID`
```

And there is some info about how to [rewrite query with subquery to query with join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/rewriting-subqueries.html) (@Barmar's solution).